# DBRef match Criteria in mongodb and spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, mongorepository

Class Car {

```
    @Id
    String id;
    String model;
    @DBRef
    List<User> users;
    @DBRef
    Company company;

}

Class User {

    @Id
    String id;
    String name;

}
```

In above example i want to search User based on user name and car model in one query.

For example search all Users who has car model ABC and User name is Sachin.

```
@Query(value="{ model : ?0 , users.name : ?1}")
```

Tried above query but getting crash.

Comment: Don't use `DBRef` if you want to make references to objects in other collections then do so "manually" and simply assign them as `ObjectId` values related to the `_id` key of those documents. `DBRef` is as "close to deprecated" as you can get, without an "official" deprecation notice. It is simply not supported in Modern features of MongoDB, and most notably [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), which generally supersedes `DBRef` as a concept anyway. It's just an old and bad idea. Not for new projects.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn let me explore lookup with match